# Laravel SQL Query. Help me

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have a table name "Offers" with 3 (public, request, private ) types of data. Now I want to show directly to the user end public and request offers. and private offers not be shown but when admin will add user_id and offer_id in a new table (offer_access) then the private offer should be available to user end for only these users.

`$offer = Offer::where('status', 'public')->orWhere('status', 'request')->latest()->get();`

I wrote this one and getting public and private offers for user end. Now I want to show private offers to a user when it available on "OfferAccess" table.

So now, How can I write the SQL query for that?

Comment: Do you have a *question*? It's unclear what your specific problem is.

Comment: My question is "How can I write the SQL query for that?"

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? Are you writing a raw query? Using eloquent? Give a [mcve].

Comment: *"How can I write the SQL query for that?"* For what? The SQL language is declarative in nature, where a `SELECT` defines *"what you what you have"* and not *"how to get it"*, which is `CREATE TABLE ..` meant for in the SQL language... So ideally you add `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name>` structures aswell.. to add to @jonrsharpe 's comment as a table structure can or data for that matter can change  the meaning of a SQL statement ...

Comment: $offer = Offer::where('status', 'public' or 'request')->latest()->get();

I wrote this one and getting public and private offers for user end.
Now I want to show private offers to a user when it available on "OfferAccess" table.

Comment: `where('status', 'public' or 'request')` isn't going to work. Look into `whereIn`.

Comment: Read the eloquent docs; you can either use `whereIn` or `orWhere`. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#where-clauses

Comment: We'll need to see relationships between models and what your tables look like to answer this. How does the `offer_access` table fit into this, from an Eloquent point of view? Is it a pivot table between two models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try blow:

```
$offer = Offer::whereIn('status', ['public', 'request'])
        ->orWhere(function($query) {
            $query->where('status', 'private')
            ->whereHas('OfferAccess', function($qry) {
                $qry->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
            });
        })->get();
```

If you need only the latest results can use `->latest()->get()` instead of only `->get()`.
Also if you need to get it for any other user than the current logged in user, then you need to pass `user_id` to closure function. so you need to use updated `orWhere` like as:

```
->orWhere(function($query) use ($user_id) {
            $query->where('status', 'private')
            ->whereHas('OfferAccess', function($qry) use ($user_id) {
                $qry->where('user_id', $user_id);
            });
        })
```

It should give you the desired results.